# Custom Action Bar Not Showing

Tags: android, android-actionbar

My activity is inflating a custom action bar to get a gradient change from opaque black to transparent when going up to down.

**EDIT:-** I changed my code and now I am getting this output:-
[image]

**My code:-**

```
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                //action bar setting
                //Getting Action Bar
                ActionBar mActionBar= getActionBar();

                LayoutInflater minflate =(LayoutInflater) mActionBar.getThemedContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                View mview = minflate.inflate(R.layout.subgrid_ab,null);

                mActionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM,ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM|ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME|ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE);
                mActionBar.setCustomView(mview, new ActionBar.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

                TextView mtext =(TextView)mview.findViewById(R.id.subgridab_text);
                  mtext.setText("General");
                setContentView(R.layout.gridsub);
}
```

It means the view is inflated but the gradient effect is still not showing.

**subgrid_ab.xml:-**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_ab"
     >

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/subgridab_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="dd"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>



</RelativeLayout>
```

**custom_ab.xml:-**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >



    <gradient
        android:startColor="#FF000000"
        android:endColor="#00000000" 
        android:angle="270"
        />

</shape>
```

So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
LayoutInflater minflate = LayoutInflater.from(this);
View mview = minflate.inflate(R.layout.subgrid_ab,null);
mActionBar.show();
```

And how ActionBar can know about your mview? 
May be it can help:

```
getActionBar().setCustomView(mview);
```

**UPDATE**

@Mohit ok, try to set "@+id" to Relative layout and set this view finded by id as the custom view to the action bar

```
View mview = minflate.inflate(R.layout.subgrid_ab,null);
View customView = mview.findViewById(R.id.yourRelativeLayoutId);

mActionBar.setCustomView(customView, new ActionBar.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```

Comment: Still getting the same output, no change!